# Qui est Jean Lefèvre, dans la chanson d'Alexis HK?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, société

La chanson ["Le ringard"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGaCreq1lR4), d'Alexis HK, est une histoire d'adultère. À un certain moment, elle fait reférence à un personnage nommé Jean Lefèvre.

```
Une voix grave d’homme m’adresse
des salutations dénuées de politesse :
“Je suis ici, me dit la voix pleine de fièvre,
je suis ici pour vous dire ma colère.
Vous êtes un imposteur, je suis le seul maître,
je me présente: je m’appelle Jean Lefèvre“
```

Qui est-ce? Est-il un personnage réel ou fictif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je pense qu'il s'agit plutôt de [Jean Lefebvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Lefebvre), un acteur qui a joué de nombreux rôles de personnages généralement niais et ringards. Ce qui n'enlève naturellement rien à ses talents d'acteur.

Answer (score 0):

Le Ringard du Placard c'est un hommage caché à Jean Lefevre, l'acteur très connu.

Comment: Très connu..  bon ça dépend de qui. Je ne connais que  [Jean Lefebvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Lefebvre). C'est lui dont tu parles ? Et si on regarde les paroles de la chanson c'est bien écrit [Lefèvre](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Alexis_HK-Le_ringard-lyrics,p02122813)

Comment: C'est bien lui.

Comment: Quels sont les indices dans les paroles qui montrent que c'est de lui qu'il s'agit ?